# how check and substitute values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array done with values from some radio buttons, say `myArray = ["1","40","35"];`

every value has his counterparts, say for instance 1 = "men", 2 = "women", 40 = "red hairs".

what's the best method to build another array where every values gets his counterpart?

so something like that `myBrandNewArray = ["men","red hairs", …];`

I should store my couples into variables for some maintenance, like

```
var "1" = "men", "2" = "women", … ;
```

but I don't know if this is a good approach…

ps. even pointing me to some resources will be great. Thank you.

Comment: "1" = "men" or men = "1" ....?

Comment: the first one, my array is populated with strings of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, finally I did this:

having

```
var numericalArray = ["1","50","45", …];
```

and

```
var couples = { "50" : "homme",     
            "1" : "femme",
            "85" : "court",     
        …
                };
```

I can call this and get a new array with coupled values:

```
function assignValues(numericalArray) {

var verbalArray = [];

for (var i=0; i<numericalArray.length; i++) {

    var value = numericalArray[i];

    verbalArray.push(couples[value]);  // right, I can't check if the values exists

}

console.log('here my new array:', verbalArray);


}
```

thanks to have me pointed on use of an object.

Answer (score 2):

I would keep a Hash of values
`hash = { '1': 'Men', '2': 'Women' ... }`

Then `[ '1', '2', ... ].map( function(v) { return hash[v]; } );`

IE9- will not accpet this, in this case you could just iterate in a for loop

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an object as [associative array](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Objects_in_JavaScript)?

```
var array = new Object();
array["1"] = "men"
array["40"] = "red hairs"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object like:

`var arr = {
 '1' : 'men',
 '2' : 'women'
}`

You can always access this easily like : `arr['1'] == 'men'`

if you want to create from existing arrays:

say `myArray` & `myBrandNewArray`

you can do something like

```
var arr = {};
foreach ( var i in myArray ) {
  arr[myArray[i]] = myBrandNewArray[i];
}
```

Comment: But with this don't I associate them by index? For instance I may or may not have "1" in 0 position, or have it at all… just curious didn't try it yet…

Comment: yeah!! right but then you'll need to explicitly set them beyond the constructs of looping.

Answer (score 0):

i think this function

```
myArray = ["1","40","35"];
myBrandNewArray = myArray.map(function(element){  /* your code to get the right array 8/ })
```

source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_map.htm

there is also a jQuery (cross browser) version of this function, for more details about that look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) `jQuery.map(myArray, function(value, index){ /*....*/ })`

Answer (score 0):

Use an object:

```
var val = {
    1: "men",
    40: "red hairs"   
};

alert(val[1]);
alert(val[2])
```

;